# LINQ with Lambda expression - Join, Group By, Sum and Count

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda

How can I "translate" this SQL query to Linq Lambda Expression:

```
    SELECT  BN.DEUF, 
            BN.DESUPERINTENDENCIAREGIONAL,
            CR.SITUACAODIVIDA, 
            COUNT(CR.VLEFETIVAMENTELIBERADO), 
            SUM(CR.VLEFETIVAMENTELIBERADO)
   FROM BENEFICIARIO BN
   JOIN CREDITO CR ON BN.CDBENEFICIARIO = CR.CDBENEFICIARIO
   GROUP BY BN.DEUF,BN.DESUPERINTENDENCIAREGIONAL, CR.SITUACAODIVIDA
   ORDER BY BN.DEUF
```

Until now I have:

```
var itens = db.CREDITO
            .Join(db.BENEFICIARIO, cr => cr.CDBENEFICIARIO, bn => bn.CDBENEFICIARIO,
                                (cr, bn) => new { cr, bn })
            .GroupBy(cr => cr.VLEFETIVAMENTELIBERADO)
            .Select(g => new { VLTOTAL = g.Sum(x => x.VLEFETIVAMENTELIBERADO) })
            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You just don't do the same group by in your sql and your linq.

So... let's do it !

```
var itens = db.CREDITO
            .Join(db.BENEFICIARIO, cr => cr.CDBENEFICIARIO, bn => bn.CDBENEFICIARIO,(cr, bn) => new { cr, bn })
            .GroupBy(x=> new{x.bn.DEUF,x.bn.DESUPERINTENDENCIAREGIONAL, x.cr.SITUACAODIVIDA})
            .Select(g => new { 
                       g.Key.DEUF,
                       g.Key.DESUPERINTENDENCIAREGIONAL,
                       g.Key.SITUACAODIVIDA,
                       VLTOTAL = g.Sum(x => x.cr.VLEFETIVAMENTELIBERADO),
                       Count = g.Count() 
                       })
            .ToList();
```

Comment: Works beautifully! Just needed to adjust `VLTOTAL = g.Sum(x => x.cr.VLEFETIVAMENTELIBERADO)`...

Comment: What if I need to select other columns that are not used to group by?

Comment: @WedadShurrab columns must either be in an aggregate function (sum, max, avg...), or in the group by clause.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to create an anonymous type in `Group By` clause to group by multiple columns. This should work:-

```
var itens = db.CREDITO
            .Join(db.BENEFICIARIO, cr => cr.CDBENEFICIARIO, bn => bn.CDBENEFICIARIO,
                                (cr, bn) => new { cr, bn })
            .GroupBy(x => new { 
                                  x.cr.SITUACAODIVIDA, 
                                  x.bn.DEUF, 
                                  x.bn.DESUPERINTENDENCIAREGIONAL 
                              }
             )
            .Select(g => new { 
                                 DEUF = g.Key.DEUF,
                                 SITUACAODIVIDA = g.Key.SITUACAODIVIDA,
                                 VLTOTAL = g.Sum(z => z.cr.VLEFETIVAMENTELIBERADO),
                                 Count = g.Count()
                             }
                   ).ToList();
```

Comment: Like a charm, too! Tks a lot! ;)